# Get Active Directory credentials from http request

Tags: java, spring, active-directory

I have a Java+Spring application.

Assuming the browser settings are all correct and site is allowed, is it possible to retrieve logged in AD user credentials from an http request? Which fields are they? AUTH_USER? Are they coming with every request (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc).

I've successfully integrated AD authentication, with the user manually typing in their AD user and password. Now i am wondering, can login be done more automatically, retrieving credential from a browser's request?

Comment: @T-Heron I have not yet decided on the final solution. I will let you know when i have successfully solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. If you want an elegant solution instead of checking each user/password in your filter for example, have an eye to JWT. You could encapsulate your AD user in it and send the token to the client, itself sending back to you in a header.

The counterpart is that you have to integrate all the jwt part, as long as JWT is not native in Spring. I'm currently working on a personal project to integrate jwt and that's not so easy for someone starting with Spring Security.

[This link seems ok for Spring](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java)